# Build hierarchy table from main nodes and level nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data, hierarchical

I'd like to build a child-parent link from data that look like this:

| id_node | main_node | level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A9 | A9 | 0 |
| 92 | A9 | 1 |
| 923 | A9 | 2 |
| 9234 | A9 | 3 |

Is there a simple way to reverse this table and add for each row, the parent id and get something like this:

| id_node | main_node | level | parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A9 | A9 | 0 | NULL |
| 92 | A9 | 1 | A9 |
| 923 | A9 | 2 | 92 |
| 9234 | A9 | 3 | 923 |

I'm not trying to loop through every id, I'd like to know if there's a method like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/getlevel-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) , but kind of reverted.

Comment: `left(id_node, len(id_node) - 1)`? You also need to take into account the `A`

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm looking for a solution that work no matter the values and the logic behind it. The id 9234 could be replaced by ZZ2 tomorrow for example.

Comment: Then how do you propose to identify the immmediate parent?

Comment: I was thinkin if there's a formula to get the node level of a row from a complete table, there might be a method to build the table from the root id + node level

Comment: Still not sure I get you, please describe the exact logic. Remember tables have no inherent ordering, you need to give an `order by`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`:

```
select t.*, tparent.id_node as parent
from t left join
     t tparent
     on tparent.main_node = t.main_node and
        tparent.level = t.level - 1;
```

You can also use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(id_node) over (partition by main_node order by level) as parent
from t
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know we can use operations like additions or substraction in the join condition.